# Intermittent Horizontal Lines on Dell Latitude 7490 Screen Despite Passing Diagnostic Tests

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, dell

I'm experiencing an issue with my Dell Latitude 7490 laptop where 19 random short horizontal lines appear on the screen. The lines are scattered across the display and appear in different positions upon each restart. I've run Dell SupportAssist's diagnostic tests, and no hardware problems were detected. Here's what I've tried so far:

- Ensuring all cable connections are secure.
- Updating the graphics drivers to the latest version.
- Checking for any damage to the monitor or cables.
- Restarting the computer multiple times, with the lines appearing in different locations on each boot.

The laptop is running Windows 10, and I haven't made any recent changes to the system or settings that I'm aware of.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on what else I can check? Could this be related to a hidden setting or is it more likely a hardware issue despite the diagnostics not finding any problems?

Laptop screen with lines:

[image]

Comment: Looks too regular to be a hardware fault. Does it show in a screenshot?

Comment: The screenshot should be taken inside Windows, not via a hand-held camera.

Comment: @Tetsujin Just FYI, because I think you enjoy learning too, Sony Trinitron CRT monitors had perfect vertical horizontal lines going across the middle of the screen.  They didn't look the OP's image, but they were due to how the hardware was manufactured (which technically wasn't a hardware fault, but was often perceived to be one).

Comment: An unlikely, but possible cause: Is it possible that those lines are a test pattern?

Comment: You mention "cable connections".  Is this an external screen or the laptop's internal screen?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate - In fact I has a series of them, from the 90s up to maybe 2010 or so; always as a pair, always with the lines. So, thanks, but yes, I was aware. :)

Comment: This is from the laptop screen, not the external monitors connected via type-c port.